# Wrapping overloaded functions in Scala (possibly using macro)

Tags: scala, overloading, scala-macros

Suppose I have types `A`, `B`, and `C`, and an overloaded method:

```
def foo(a: A): C
def foo(b: B): C
```

Then suppose I have a (complicated) piece of code that works with objects of type `C`. What I would like to have is a method that takes either type `A` or `B`:

```
def bar(x: [A or B]) = {
  val c = foo(x)
  // Code that works with c
}
```

Of course I could write two versions of `bar`, overloaded to take types `A` and `B`, but in this case, there are multiple functions that behave like `bar`, and it would be silly to have overloaded versions (in my actual case, there are three versions of `foo`) for all of them.

C-style macros would be perfect here, so I thought to look into Scala macros. The awkward part is that Scala macros are still typed-checked, so I can't just say

```
reify(foo(x.splice))
```

since the compiler wants to know the type of `x` beforehand. I'm entirely new to using Scala macros (and it's a substantial API), so some pointers in this regard would be appreciated.

Or if there's a way to layout this code without macros, that would be helpful too!

Comment: You probably could do something like this with macros, but it's really, really not a good idea (and I say that as a fan of Scala's macro system). Use a type class instead.

Comment: Yeah, type class is a neat idea. Still, I wonder (for educational purposes) if there's a way to do with with a macro? Seems like it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem differently.

Instead of say type `A or B` think about what you want from those types. In your example it would be enough if you said: "It doesn't matter what type it is, as long as I have a `foo` method for it". That's what the code below shows:

```
trait FooMethod[T] {
  def apply(t:T):C
}

object FooMethod {
  implicit val forA = new FooMethod[A] {
    def apply(a:A):C = foo(a)
  }

  implicit val forB = new FooMethod[B] {
    def apply(b:B):C = foo(b)
  }
}

def bar[X](x: X)(implicit foo:FooMethod[X]) = {
  val c = foo(x)
  // Code that works with c
}
```